# How to pass a string that specifies columns to be printed to awk?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a file with a large number of space separated columns. I want to print specific columns based on certain numerical criteria in a dynamic way. For example:

```
]$ cols=$(for i in `seq 1 3`; do echo -n "\$$[$[i-1]*6+1],\$$[$[i-1]*6+2],\$$[$[i-1]*6+3],\$$[$[i-1]*6+4+66],\$$[$[i-1]*6+5+66],\$$[$[i-1]*6+6+66],"; done)
```

which gives me the columns I want to print out:

```
]$ echo ${cols%?}
$1,$2,$3,$70,$71,$72,$7,$8,$9,$76,$77,$78,$13,$14,$15,$82,$83,$84
```

when I pass this to awk as a string, I don't get what I want:

```
]$ awk -v cols=${cols%?} '{print cols}' file-testawk | head -2
$1,$2,$3,$70,$71,$72,$7,$8,$9,$76,$77,$78,$13,$14,$15,$82,$83,$84
$1,$2,$3,$70,$71,$72,$7,$8,$9,$76,$77,$78,$13,$14,$15,$82,$83,$84
```

awk treats it as a string rather than column identifiers.

How can I pass a string of columns to print out to awk in a way that will be correctly recognized? I'm looking for a simple, more-or-less one-liner solution, e.g. like this:

```
cols=$(for i in `seq 1 3`; do echo -n "\$$[$[i-1]*6+1],\$$[$[i-1]*6+2],\$$[$[i-1]*6+3],\$$[$[i-1]*6+4+66],\$$[$[i-1]*6+5+66],\$$[$[i-1]*6+6+66],"; done); awk -v cols=${cols%?} '{print cols}' file-testawk > file.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk does not have eval like capabilities but you can make a trick using `awk -f` capability (read script from file) combined with bash process substitution:

```
$ a="\$1,\$4"
$ echo "$a"
$1,$4
$ a="{print $a}"
$ echo "$a"
{print $1,$4}
$ awk -f <(echo "$a") <<<"one two three four five"
one four
```

Comment: Beautiful. `awk -f <(echo "{print ${cols%?}}") file-testawk | head -2` works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**Usage:** `./pass_numbers_to_awk.sh` Explanation in comments.

```
#!/bin/bash

#generate random string of numbers - simulation column's numbers 
for i in {1..2}; do
    for j in {1..3}; do
        num=$(( (i-1) * 6 + j ))
        #numbers separated by vertical bar symbol 
        string_of_numbers+="${num}|"
    done
done

# pass to awk string like a "1|2|3|7|8|9|13|14|15|", 
# removing last vertical bar "|"
##
# use the awk split function - for information 
# look at the 'man mawk | grep -A 3 split\(s,A,r\)'
##      
# go through array and print specified columns.

awk -v string_from_bash="${string_of_numbers%?}" '
BEGIN {
    num_of_cols = split(string_from_bash, array_of_columns, "|");
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= num_of_cols; i++) {

        # Prevent trailing spaces emergence
        OFS = (i > 1) ? " " : ""

        printf "%s%s", OFS, $array_of_columns[i];
    }
    printf "\n";
}' < input.txt
```

**Creating the input.txt file for testing:** `./create_table.sh > input.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {A..O}; do
    for j in {1..10}; do
        echo -n "column_${j} "
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: awk `for(idx in ary)` is allowed to enumerate idx values in effectively random order, and almost always does, which garbles your output. gawk 4 has a nondefault option to sort them; `for(i=1; i in ary; i++) ... ary[i] ...` or `n=split(,ary,); ... for(i=1; i<=n; i++) ...ary[i] ...` work portably.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, didn't know about it. Changed the code.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is adept at doing these index calculations, so this:

```
awk -v N=3 '
   {
   for ( i=1; i<= N; ++i )
      print $((i-1)*6+1), $((i-1)*6+2), $((i-1)*6+3), $((i-1)*6+4+66), $((i-1)*6+5+66), $((i-1)*6+6+66)
   }
' data.file
```

Basic idea being, if you give awk a number stored in a variable `i` then `awk` can fetch the field corresponding to that number via `$(i)`. Now `i` can as well be an expression also as is the case here.

Comment: This is good, but it is not very dynamic. Basically, I don't want to do anything in awk because `for i in \`seq 1 3\`` can change randomly, e.g. `for i in 2 4 6 13 21` as well as the functional dependences on `$i`.